# How to set the length of a constraint from a sub view to a parent view by the parent views percentage in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, constraints, percentage

Preferably using storyboard.

This is another one of those things you would imagine to be so simple it shouldn't be thought of.

The only way i know how to add a constraint to a subview is in storyboard i click on the constraint button on bottom left. However, the only way to set a constraint is by constants which make no sense because the resolution of apple devices change. So if you were to put a constant constraint of one subview to 50 for example on an iPhone 5s and everything looks good, on an iPad everything is way off which thinner and/or thicker spaces.

You would think percentage would be the main way to go and constants should be more difficult to access.

Anyways please let me know how to do this. In the answers found online i only saw ways to do it in code but i would like to keep it all in story board if possible.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking, but setting a constraint's multiplier to something less than 1 works for relative sizing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I have played around with the multiplayer a lot and it doesn't seem to be getting a percentage of the SuperView. It seems to be getting a percentage of just the constraint itself. @PhillipMills

Comment: What if you set a constraint on the subview height so it's equal to the superview height and then use a 0.xx multiplier?